Creating new linked services returns InvalidCredentialReference
I'm running a trial version of Azure and I have a SQL Server database with tables. I've also gone to Resources -> Managed Identity and added myself.
These are the steps I'm taking and where I see the error in Linked Services:

Authentication type -> selected servername/db name
User Assigned Managed Identity -> create new credentials -> 'c1' -> select the identity name I created in the 1st step which populated

I go to test connection and it fails with:

Invalid credential reference. Name: c1  Activity ID:
34dksdfe-.... error code
InvalidCredentialReference

Edit: I'm trying to use Linked Services in Data Factory. When I add a new service, select azure sql database and try to connect by selecting authentication type.
I've tried SQL Authentication but I don't know the password, I have the username but when I click reset password nothing happens. Now I'm trying with User Assigned Managed Identity.
I've also tried with System  Assigned Managed Identity but I see the error:

Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the
SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access. Login
failed for user ''.


Assigned Managed Identity is the identity of the Server when Server makes a call to other Azure resources. But it seems that you want to connect to the Server, right? Can you please provide more context? Who should connect to who and why you need a user-assigned identity?

@VladDX - I've updated my question let me know if more context is needed


It's not clear what you assign the identity to. To Data Factory that is going to read from SQL Server or to SQL Server? The latter is not relevant at all to a case when Data Factory reading from SQL Server.



It's not clear how you are testing the connection. Can you elaborate?


@KristiLuna Have you given the managed identity permissions on the SQL server?
